# Preprocessor macro for Apple Watch?

Tags: ios, preprocessor, watchkit, c-preprocessor, watchos-2

I was looking at Apple's [Lister (for Apple Watch, iOS, and OS X)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/samplecode/Lister/Listings/Objective_C_ListerKitTests_AAPLIncompleteListItemsPresenterTests_m.html) sample. The sample performs a test for iOS and OS X:

```
#import <TargetConditionals.h>

#if (TARGET_OS_IPHONE || TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)

@import ListerKit;

#elif TARGET_OS_MAC

@import ListerKitOSX;

#endif
```

However, there is no test for `TARGET_OS_WATCH` or similar. Grepping for `watch` in `TargetConditionals.h` delivers no hits:

```
$ cat /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer
  /SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk/usr/include/TargetConditionals.h | grep -i watch
$
```

From `TargetConditionals.h`, I know there are:

```
    These conditionals specify in which Operating System the generated code will
    run. The MAC/WIN32/UNIX conditionals are mutually exclusive.  The EMBEDDED/IPHONE 
    conditionals are variants of TARGET_OS_MAC. 

        TARGET_OS_MAC           - Generate code will run under Mac OS
        TARGET_OS_WIN32         - Generate code will run under 32-bit Windows
        TARGET_OS_UNIX          - Generate code will run under some non Mac OS X unix 
        TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED      - Generate code will run under an embedded OS variant
                                  of TARGET_OS_MAC
        TARGET_OS_IPHONE        - Generate code will run under iPhone OS which 
                                  is a variant of TARGET_OS_MAC.
    TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR     - Generate code for running under iPhone Simulator
```

**Question**: Is there a preprocessor for Apple's watch?

---

I'm tagging with [ios](/questions/tagged/ios), but I'm not sure that's the correct OS for this question.

The list below was compiled from iPhone's `TargetConditionals.h`. The Simulator and OS X are similar (they just have different bits set to 1):

```
#define TARGET_OS_MAC               1
#define TARGET_OS_WIN32             0
#define TARGET_OS_UNIX              0
#define TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED          1 
#define TARGET_OS_IPHONE            1 
#define TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR     0
```

**Questions**: Does the watch use `TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED`? Does the watch *omit* `TARGET_OS_IPHONE`?

Comment: When `clang` is compiling, the `-target ${ARCH}-apple-watchos6.2` command-line arg with `-mwatchos-version-min=6.2` arg causes right macros to be defined (and simulator-build passes `-mwatchsimulator-version-min=6.2` arg instead of second one)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As of watchOS 2.0, you can run native code on the watch, so this is a more relevant question.

I'm using the first early beta of watchOS 2, so this may change, but right now, `TARGET_OS_WATCH` is set to 1 on watchOS.

(Also, be careful: `TARGET_OS_IPHONE` is also set to 1 on watchOS, though `TARGET_OS_IOS` is 0.)

Answer (score 27):

You can find all kind of target conditionals in the TargetConditionals.h (cmd + shift + o and type TargetConditionals.h).

In this list you can find a list like this and many more useful defines.
Currently it does contain TARGET_OS_WATCH since WatchOS 2. For WatchOS 1 it was not possible to run custom code on the watch so it was not needed back then since everything ran on the phone itself.

```
#define TARGET_OS_MAC               1
#define TARGET_OS_WIN32             0
#define TARGET_OS_UNIX              0
#define TARGET_OS_IPHONE            1 
#define TARGET_OS_IOS               0
#define TARGET_OS_WATCH             1
#define TARGET_OS_TV                0
#define TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR         0
#define TARGET_OS_EMBEDDED          1
```

**Swift Addition**

```
#if os(watchOS)
    [Watch code]
#else
    [Code for iOS, appleTV, or any else clause]
#endif
```

Some other valid values: iOS, OSX, tvOS

A small explanation about this and more http://nshipster.com/swift-system-version-checking/

At the bottom of this document
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_15#Build Configurations
Under the section 'Build Configurations' you can find a (hopefully) up to date list with all these values that are currently available

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. As of 2019, `#if os(iOS)` still works great. This was needed for me to get `WCSessionDelegate` code running properly when using the same class across iOS and watchOS.

Answer (score 8):

There is no WatchKit or app extension target conditional. But you can create your own per-target conditionals that you use in the same way.

If you look in the "Build Settings" section for any target, there's a section called "Other C Flags". Add an entry for the WatchKit target. If you add something like `-DMY_WATCHKIT_FLAG=1`, you can then do `#if MY_WATCHKIT_FLAG` in code.

Make your custom flag, well, custom. It's not impossible that Apple might add a flag in the future called something like `TARGET_WATCH_APP` or whatever. Use a prefix on the flag name to make it specific to you.

Comment: At the time of the question, I should have accepted this answer. I'm not sure why I did not. But as fate would have it, Apple added `TARGET_OS_WATCH`. Sorry about the delay.

Answer (score 2):

With the current WatchKit SDK, all code in a Watch application runs on the phone it’s paired with, so there’s no point at which your preprocessor is going to encounter code that’s going to run on the Watch and thus not much use for a macro to tell it what to do when it does. The code in the ListerWatch target of the sample you linked to will run as an extension on the iPhone and talk to its watch UI via WatchKit.

Comment: You could have a shared manager class which invokes [UIApplication sharedApplication] which is forbidden on watch but you know will never be called or might want to overwrite by using this macro.